# Как получить значение ячейки из DataGrid в коде?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, wpf-datagrid

Коллекция `public ObservableCollection<StudentModel> Students { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<StudentModel>();`

Таким образом нахожу DataGrid: `DataGrid str = (DataGrid)App.Current.MainWindow.FindName("TableName");`

Есть команда, которой пытаюсь задать условие выполнения и не получается.

```
public RelayCommand<StudentModel> endGame = null;
public RelayCommand<StudentModel> EndGame => endGame ?? (endGame = new RelayCommand<StudentModel>((param) =>
    {
        ChangeTextColorToDefault();

        str.IsEnabled = false;
        timer.Stop();
        deviceManager.votumManager.Stop();
    },
        (param) =>
        {
            var x = str.CurrentCell.Item;
            return str.IsEnabled; //|| x?.Text != default;
        }));
```

Нужно задать условие таким образом, чтобы кнопка была доступна, когда у объектов в DataGrid'e изменилось хотя бы одно св-во, при чём param недоступен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось вот так:

```
var x = str.Columns[7].GetCellContent(str.Items[0]) as TextBlock;
```